# WPF System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have the following code which is opening a dialog to indicate to the user the application is processing in another thread, which then will close the window once it receives the LoadCompletedEvent. However I always get the following error and not really sure to what specifically it is referring to.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.
```

This is how the thread is being created.

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            MetroProgressWindow metroProgressWindow = new MetroProgressWindow(this);
            metroProgressWindow.ShowDialog();
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        //thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Name = "omega-thread";
        thread.Start();

        // create window, do loading, business logic, etc            

        // throw load completed event
        LoadCompletedEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;     // hide MainWindow
        renderWindow.ShowDialog();          // show the RenderWindow as a modal dialog NOTE: this is thread blocking
```

And then in the other window code behind looks like this.

```
public partial class MetroProgressWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MetroProgressWindow(IOmegaWindow window)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        window.LoadCompletedEvent += delegate
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(() => { this.Close(); }),
                null);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume, you are using MahApps?

Comment: I am using MahApps. the new object[2] didn't work, however when doing further debugging it is failing on metroProgressWindow.ShowDialog(); which doesn't take any arguments

Comment: The fact that ShowDialog takes no arguments is completely irrelevant: it activates the window's logic, where the problem is that Action expects no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is caused by the `null` parameter in the `BeginInvoke`.
Try for instance without it:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(() => { this.Close(); }));
```